# Make Genymotion use a host VPN

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn, android, cisco-vpn-client

I'm using Cisco's AnyConnect to connect to a VPN using my Windows 8.1 PC. When using the Genymotion emulator, I would like it to use the VPN too. However, although having Internet access from the device, I can't connect to IPs in the VPN.
Since Genymotion uses VirtualBox, I have tried disabling the first adapter (the host-only adapter) from VirtualBox's configuration, and left the second adapter enabled (a NAT adapter). However, it wouldn't work ([I took that idea from this answer](https://superuser.com/a/728009/384156)).

Do you have any ideas on how could I share this VPN access to my device?

Best regards.

Comment: I am having the same problems, did you figure something out by now?

Comment: Sorry, it's been a long time and I never had the chance to make it work (in fact, I haven't worked in Android for more than a year). Anyway, I seem to remember you could use Android Studio's emulator, instead of Genymotion, and you would have access to the VPN doing so. Hope this works for you

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use the official emulator, as it runs too slow. But thanks for your answer anyways.